# How to put a frame and a color caption to graphics

Tags: captions

[image]

Hello,

i guess it is the easiest way to show you in a picture what i want to do :-)

I want to have all my grafics with the same style:
- color caption
- frame grafic

So I have to change just the filename, and the captiontext.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Is this a LaTeX question at all? Can't you use a function plotter to generate the graphics with the relevant features?

Comment: What package are you using for plot? What document class are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I found this with a quick reading in the tcolorbox documentation

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\newtcolorbox[blend into=figures]{myfigure}[2][]{%With blend into you can standardize all your figures
float=htb,
capture=hbox,
title={#2},
every float=\centering,#1,
colframe=blue,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
colback=yellow}

\begin{myfigure}{Figure name}
\includegraphics{Image}
\end{myfigure}

\end{document}
```